# Incluir una página .php dependiendo de la opción seleccionada en una lista desplegable

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web y me gustaría incluir una pagina .php diferente para cada opción del `select`. Probé con `include` y con `require` pero sigue sin funcionarme.

He probado a hacer esto, pero no me funciona:

```
   <select id="idioma" name="idioma">
              <option action="<?php require ('../Vista/lang/lang_es.php'); ?>" value="es" selected="selected">Español</option>
              <option action="<?php require ( '../Vista/lang/lang_en.php'); ?>" value="en">Inglés</option>
    </select>
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: hola @adamista, lo que quieres lograr es un  redirect ?

Comment: No, lo que quiero es incluir el archivo .php dependiendo de la opción para que así pueda acceder a las variables que hay declaradas en él

Comment: ¿cómo son las variables en lang_es.php y lang_en.php?¿Son variables de PHP o de JavaScript?

Comment: Es código php, por ejemplo: <?php define('CASA','casa'); ?>

Comment: bien ten en cuenta que estas del lado del cliente, hacer esto una vez cargado el documento no debería ser posible, salvo con jquery o hacer un submit al seleccionar una opción.

Comment: ¿Y como se podría hacer con jquery?

Comment: Hola @adamista, estás preguntando por algo que no tiene sentido, cuando se ejecuta la página en el navegador, el código PHP ya ha sido ejecutado y ya no existen mas variables. jQuery no tiene nada que ver con la funcionalidad que deseas. Puedes explicarnos ¿que es lo que tratas de hacer **realmente** (por qué quieres acceder a variables de una u otra pagina desde el lado cliente) para que así podamos ayudarte?

Comment: con jquery puede hacer un .load().

Comment: Tengo dos archivos con constantes definidas y quiero que dependiendo de la opción seleccionada en la lista desplegable se pueda acceder a las variables de un archivo o del otro.

Comment: puedes hacer un request AJAX, dependiendo de la seleccion traes lo que necesites

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que intentas hacer no es viable ya que estas del lado del cliente.

Se me ocurre esa manera de hacerlo:

### Mediante un post

```
<?php 

$includes=array(
         'en'=>'../Vista/lang/lang_en.php',
         'es'=>'../Vista/lang/lang_es.php'
         );

if(isset($_POST['idioma']) && array_key_exists($_POST['idioma'], $includes)) :
    include($includes[$_POST['idioma']]);
endif;
?>

<form id="selection_form" action="" method="post">
    <select name="idioma" id="idioma">
    <option value ="es">Español</option>
    <option value ="en">Inglés</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="idioma_submit" value="GET FILE">
</form>
```

Comment: Bien, así lo conseguí. Muchas gracias :D

Comment: Perfecto @adamista, me alegra haberte ayudado, no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta.